# Update custom attribute for federated user in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I want to add `current_account_id` - custom attribute claim to access_token. We have a feature where users can change their account.

To achieve that, I have created a custom mapper protocol and it works fine for Non federated user. Below is the flow

1. User logs in first-time `current_account_id` claim will be null in access_token so set default_account_in in the web app.
2. Once the user changes the account, make an API call to the Keycloak app to update the value of the above custom attribute (current_account_id) so it will become 2 now
3. Now new access_token will have value 2 as current_account_id

This flow works fine for Non-Federated users.

For the federated users, I have created a column in my web app's users table named as current_account_id and once user logs in I set it as per this [code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/model/legacy/src/main/java/org/keycloak/storage/adapter/AbstractUserAdapter.java#L338). But it only works when the user logs in. Once user changes the account, I update the current_account_id column in the users table and I expect this custom attribute to be updated but that is not happening.

Comment: Ok, so you change id on some federated user storage and this change is not reflected on Keycloak side? I mean Keycloak still uses own cache that is evicted only on user login, right?

Comment: That is my assumption. As I mentioned, If I update custom attribute using Admin REST (Update user) API call for non-federated user, then access_token is having new value of custom attribute. And I want to achieve the same for the federated users.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification, wanted to confirm it, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is standard Keycloak behaviour - data for mappers is directly from provider, but it is performed during login: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#storage-mode

Here is similar issue, cache eviction could help:
https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-June/011091.html

Comment: I went through the articles above but can you tell me exactly where I need to write a code for cache eviction for that user?

Comment: You can setup cache policy in User Federation settings, or clear cache using: /{realm}/clear-user-cache with POST method. I didn't use clearing per user, I saw some model available for it but not sure if API is exposed.